# Android Joda Time, Having trouble sorting strings from ISOPeriodFormat

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, jodatime

I've been looking everywhere for a solution but can't manage to find one that works.

I have a "Scoreboard" that needs to show the highest "times" (period between two instants) the app has calculated with Joda Time.

All the strings are stocked in an ArrayList and displayed through an ArrayAdapter and a ListView.

The problem : Collections.sort doesn't seem to work properly even with ISO format.

i'm saving the time using the format :

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = ISOPeriodFormat.standard();
```

Which gives out this : "PT1M15.664S" 
(1 min 15seconds)

That i convert to a string and store into the ArrayList.

How can i sort these strings so it goes from the longest to the shortest amount of time in my Scoreboard ?

I've tried natural sorting and Alphanum Comparator with no luck. Every time it passes a cap (minutes, hours, days) the values get like this :

```
"PT2.455S"
"PT1.324S"
"PT1M15.333S"
```

Instead of what i would like :

```
"PT1M15.333S"
"PT2.455S"
"PT1.324S"
```

Using Collection.sort(myArrayList) doesn't work either.

Any idea what i should do ?

My code :

```
 // set is a set<String> retrieving it's values from a stringset scores saved
in the sharedpreferences of the app

 set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("scores", null);

 //scores is the ArrayList
 scores.clear();


  if (set != null){

      scores.addAll(set);

  }else{

      scores.add("No Time Yet!");
      set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
      set.addAll(scores);
      sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("scores",set).apply();
  }

//removing the String No Time Yet because it no longer serves a purpose here
  if ((set != null)&& (set.size()>1)){
      scores.remove("No Time Yet!");
  }


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,scores);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Collections.sort(scores);
```

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Idea: Don't sort on the string values. Sort the Joda periods *before* converting them to strings.

Comment: Of course, you'd first have to define the sort order, e.g. is `P30DT2H` more or less than `P1M`? Is `PT23H30M` more or less than `P1D`? If you're observing Daylight Savings Time, the answer is *less*, except for one day of the year, where it is *more*. Similarly `PT24H` and `P1D` are equal, except for 2 days each year.

Comment: It would be a great idea, but i can't save periods as part of the sharedpreferences in android (i'm getting the values from another activity), so i'm stuck with the String set.

Comment: Then parse them back to periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use the class [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#Duration-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-), not `Period`.

**Explanation:**

Your general approach using the class `Period` is wrong. This type represents a tuple of various amount-unit-pairs. Some of them are not convertible or comparable. For example, it is impossible to determine if P30D is greater or equal to or smaller than P1M (think of February, April or August). So it is pretty clear why **you cannot sort by periods** resp. why this class does not implement the interface `Comparable`. And this objection is valid for the objects of type `Period` as well as for its canonical ISO-representation (as String).

But since you want

> the highest "times" (period between two instants)

you can use `Duration` to determine the absolute amount of elapsed seconds and milliseconds between two given instants. This type is comparable and only has two minor constraints which are probably not important for you:

- precision limited to milliseconds
- ignores leap seconds

I recommend to compare duration objects, not strings because you want a chronological order, not a lexicographical order. So you could use the String-representation of `Duration` (like PT72.345S) for storage but parse it for comparison:

```
Instant i1 = new Instant(0);
Instant i2 = new Instant(72_345);
Duration d1 = new Duration(i1, i2);

Instant i3 = new Instant(60_000);
Instant i4 = new Instant(200_710);
Duration d2 = new Duration(i3, i4);

List<String> scoreTimes = new ArrayList<>();
scoreTimes.add(d1.toString());
scoreTimes.add(d2.toString());

// order from longest times to shortest times
Collections.sort(
    scoreTimes,
    new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Duration.parse(s2).compareTo(Duration.parse(s1));
        }
    }
);

System.out.println(scoreTimes); // [PT140.710S, PT72.345S]
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for explaining this so well. I understand now why what i was doing didn't work. I followed your example and everything is working fine !